# Rails 5/rspec/capybara: How do I write a feature request for an AJAX form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a remote form that I want to test.

My feature test looks like this:

```
RSpec.feature 'User creates a foobar' do
  scenario 'they see the foobar on the page' do
    get '/apply', :js

    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Joe Bloggs'

    click_button 'Submit application'
    #...
```

However, `click_button 'Submit application'` breaks with the error:

```
*** ActionController::UnknownFormat Exception: ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

My controller only responds in JS. There are no redirects/renders. I want to eventually check the record exists in the database.

What do I need to do to ensure it doesn't break when the response is `js`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run with a JS capable driver - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#drivers - which in a default setup can be as easy as specifying the driver (`Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium_chrome` for chrome via selenium, etc.) and setting `js: true` metadata for the test. Also note that you can't use direct request methods (`get`, `post`, etc) when using Capybara - you have to tell it to visit the page instead.

```
RSpec.feature 'User creates a foobar', js: true do # `js: true` applies to all scenarios in this feature - could be put on single scenario instead if desired
  scenario 'they see the foobar on the page' do  
    visit '/apply'

    fill_in 'Name', with: 'Joe Bloggs'

    click_button 'Submit application'
    #...
```